# How to implement instapaper in an iPhone app development?

Tags: iphone, save

I want to add instapaper feature in my iPhone app project. My project contains reading articles from a particular site in iPhone. I want to add a feature in it to save articles on instapaper and we can view those save articles in some other area. I have worked on saving the article on instapaper by taking user credentials. But I am not able to retrieve saved data from instapaper. So, can anybody tell me any tutorial or other thing that can help me in retrieving saved data in a user account from instapaper.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that only [Instapaper subscribers](http://www.instapaper.com/subscription) (currently $1/month) can access their saved articles from the API. Others can only save articles and list folders. The full API is still in beta, but you can find documentation here: [Instapaper Full Developer API Documentation](http://www.instapaper.com/api/full).